# Applescript : Quicktime X Export to 720

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, quicktime

Looking for help (really to do) with a script/automator action for opening a files in QT X and using the export 720p command. I do not want to use the encode feature built into the finder. Using the "export" feature in QT X with the files I'm working does the trick and does not re-encode the files. I tried using automator but there is no "export" action only "encode" which re-encodes the files.

I see the command in the dictionary but can't seem to make it work.

i've seen a lot of scripting help but mostly for QT 7 and Pro. Not so much for X

is this possible?

Thanks in advance for your talent and skill,

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    set movieName to the name of the front document
    set savePath to a reference to POSIX file ¬
        ("/Users/WBTVPOST/Desktop/" & movieName & ".mov")
    export the front document in savePath using settings preset "720p"
end tell
```

<sup>**System info:** *AppleScript version:* `2.7`  *System version:* `10.13.6`</sup>

Comment: That's it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking for QuickTime Player Applescript dictionary, it looks quite simple using Export command like in script bellow :

```
set MyFile to choose file name  -- open save as dialog to fill path and file name
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    export (document 1) in MyFile using settings preset "720p"
end tell
```

However, if QuickTime is correctly performing the export (you can see progress bar of export by QuickTime), I always end up with error (no permission to write exported file)...even if the destination folder is my Desktop !!

I think it is a bug in the QuickTime Applescript command. May be someone knows how to deal with that ?

Then, I used a work around using GUI scripting. I try to avoid GUI scripting, but in this case, I did not find how. Therefore, the script must simulate the user click of the export menu and then fill the save-as dialog box. Doing that, QuickTime has no permission issue !

Here is the script with many comments :

```
set FileName to "test720p" -- your file name for the 720p exported video
set DestFolder to "myFolder/mySubFolder" -- path from Documents folder (folders should exit !!)
tell application "QuickTime Player" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell process "QuickTime Player"

    --click menu 720p  of menu "Export" which is item 16 of menu File which is 3rd menu of main menu bar
    click menu item 2 of menu 1 of menu item 16 of menu 1 of menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1
    delay 1 -- leave time to open save as dialog

    -- need to fill the save as dialog box
    keystroke "h" using {command down, shift down} -- go home directory
    keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down} -- go-to dialog
    keystroke DestFolder
    keystroke return -- close go-to dialog
    keystroke FileName -- fill save as file name on top
    keystroke return -- close the save-as dialog    
end tell
```

There are other command keys in standard save-as dialog box (to go to other standard folders). up to you to adjust to your needs. Make sure your folders in DestFolder are already created before !

Comment: Yea. I ran into the same permissions problem when I tried you original script. Very strange. I hope that with some modifications I can make the GUI script work for me. Thank you.